# Error with getting an index of a dataframe from a list of dataframes - python

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing, valueerror

I'm trying to getting an index of a value (dataframe) from a list.
The problem is if I'm looking for the value that happens to be in index 0 it works, otherwise it gives an error.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,0]
c = []
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
c.append(df1)
c.append(df2)
print("c", c)
print("Frame1", c.index(df1))
print("Frame2", c.index(df2))
```

and this is the error that I get when running the last line:
`ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

What is the error exactly and what should be done?

Comment: This will give an error because ```list.index(x)``` gives the first item whose value is equal to x. In this case x is a dataframe. And comparing df1 to df2 will give that error as it will compare element by element.

Comment: An alternative might be something like this ```c.index(df2, c.index(df1) +1)``` but if your aim is to store multiple dataframe in a variable and then access them, use a dict instead. something like ```c = {} ``` and then you can access them easily ```c['df1'] = df1```

Comment: I didn't occure to me to use dict, thank you